# Azure function not triggered by EventHubTrigger

Tags: c#, azure, function, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an event hub that has a load of events in it. I also have an Azure function written in C#, but it's not receiving any events. This is what the setup looks like:

Function:

```
private const string EventHubName = "eventhub";
private const string ConnectionStringName = "Settings:EventHubConsumerConnectionstring";

[FunctionName("InformationHandler")]
public async Task RunAsync(
    [EventHubTrigger(EventHubName, Connection = ConnectionStringName)] EventData[] eventData,
    ILogger log)
```

Host.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "aggregator": {
        "batchSize": 1000,
        "flushTimeout": "00:01:00"
    },
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true
            }
        }
    },
    "extensions": {
        "eventHubs": {
            "batchCheckpointFrequency": 1,
            "eventProcessorOptions": {
                "maxBatchSize": 64,
                "prefetchCount": 128
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output when running:

```
Functions:

        InformationHandler: eventHubTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2021-02-25T21:48:01.621Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000DC59BDB5'.
```

I'm using netcoreapp3.1 with Azure Functions 3. I have the following NuGet packages installed:

[image]

Does anyone know why I'm not receiving any events? The connection string is correct and it can find the settings in my settings file.

Comment: Did you run with `--verbose`? Hope event hub is not paused? Though that might give you explicit errors. Last thing I recommend is to deploy to cloud and see logs in Portal A) YourApp->Functions->YourFunction->Monitor if it's invokved B) Goto Logs tab and set level to verbose and wait, I've seen "polling logs" there which I've not seen anywhere else. Finally though you said `The connection string is correct and it can find the settings in my settings file.`, would be good if you post the settings. NOTE: Set `samplingSettings.isEnabled` to false while you're developing. HTH.

Comment: Any error output?

Comment: Please make you're using the `event hub namespace level` connection string, and you can also create a new `consumer group` and use the new `consumer group` in your azure function.

Comment: @Kashyap thank you. When running it manually from the console (`func start --build`) it suddenly works. I expect it's a rider issue.

Comment: @LeonCullens Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. Here are some points you can check:

1.Please make you're using the `event hub namespace level` connection string.

2.you can also create a new `consumer group` and use the new `consumer group` in your azure function.

3.It may be a temp issue. Just restart your function or create a new function to see if it can work.